# How to count duplicates of my array?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using Wordpress and I'm querying a CPT. Here is a **single** output example:

```
Array
(
    [0] => WP_Post Object
        (
            [ID] => 1400
            [post_author] => 1
            [post_date] => 2017-10-20 14:43:48
            [post_date_gmt] => 2017-10-20 13:43:48
            [post_content] => content
            [post_title] => test-case
            [post_excerpt] => dsfsdfsd
            [post_status] => publish
            [comment_status] => closed
            [ping_status] => closed
            [post_password] => 
            [post_name] => test-case
            [to_ping] => 
            [pinged] => 
            [post_modified] => 2017-10-20 15:02:43
            [post_modified_gmt] => 2017-10-20 14:02:43
            [post_content_filtered] => 
            [post_parent] => 0
            [guid] => http://example.com/site/?post_type=bulletin&p=1400
            [menu_order] => 0
            [post_type] => bulletin
            [post_mime_type] => 
            [comment_count] => 0
            [filter] => raw
        )
)
```

I have a lot of duplicate posts with the same title but they use a UID which is contained in the `post_meta` (not display here in this example as it's irrelevant)

I use this code to loop through all posts, find the duplicates and create a new array containing a single instance of the posts that are duplicated.

```
foreach ($query->posts as $post) {

  if (!array_key_exists($post->bid, $new_array)) {

    $new_array[$post->bid] = $post;  

  }

}
```

**Question:** How can I additionally count the duplicates of each post with the loop above?

Comment: $i =0; and an else with $i++;?

Comment: @AneesSaban Feel free to post a code example

Comment: So your only criterion on whether a post is a duplicate is the `post_title` ?

Comment: @apokryfos Yes. Everyitme a new post is added, another 7-20 or so duplicates are also added... it's just that with the duplicate ones, they have a different geographical 'location' associated with the post (locations contained in meta data). The titles will always be the same so it's ok to use `post_title`

Comment: Why has this been down voted??????  People be so quick to negatively impact your posts without explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to count them you can do this:

```
$duplicateCounts = array_count_values(array_map(function ($post) {
     return $post->post_title;
},$query->posts);

foreach ($query->posts as $post) {
   if (!array_key_exists($post->bid, $new_array)) {    
       $new_array[$post->bid] = $post;       
       $new_array[$post->bid]->duplicate_count = $duplicateCounts[$post->post_title];
    }    
}
```

What it does is:

1. It transform the `$query->posts` result array into an array of only the `post_title` value. This is done by using [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) which would change the result of each array entry based on the result of the function (in this case to get the `post_title`) and will return the result in a new array.
2. Count the number of instances of each title within the new array, this is done using [`array_count_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) which will (according to the manual) "return an array using the values of array as keys and their frequency in array as values.". E.g. if you had `test-case` 12 times in the original array it would have an entry like `[ "test-case" => 12 ]` in the frequency array.

Once all this is done it's just a matter of checking the frequency array for how many times a title was found.

Comment: Great, that did the trick. Please could you add explanatory comments on how this code works exactly so that I may learn this and not just copy & paste?

Comment: @ProEvilz added some more info. Hopefully its useful.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to throw in a counter into your existing code. It seems like a bit of an odd question, but we all have those "woods for trees" moments, so here you go:

```
$duplicates = 0;
foreach ($query->posts as $post) {

    if (!array_key_exists($post->bid, $new_array)) {

        $new_array[$post->bid] = $post;  

    }
    else {
        $duplicates++;
    }

}
```

Comment: This will count **all** duplicates, I was after duplicates for **each** post. So to be clear, as an example, there would be `4 x Foo` posts, `4 x Bar` posts `3 x Baz` posts (same title, different content). With my current code, I can get 1 x of each post (by title) but I needed how many duplicates **each** one had.

Comment: Ok, then you'd need to create an array for each title and Add to it with each repetition. Are the repeated titles always straight after one another before another title comes along?